# Java regular expression nongreedy issue

Tags: java, regex

I would like to match the smallest sub string that starts with d and ends with a and contains o.

Example :  "djswxaeqobdnoa" => "dnoa"

With this code :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("d.*?o.*?a");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("fondjswxaeqobdnoajezbpfrehanxi");
while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

The entire input string "djswxaeqobdnoa" printed instead of just "dnoa". Why ? How can I match the smallest ?

Here a solution :

```
String shortest = null;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?=(d.*?o.*?a))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("ondjswxaeqobdnoajezbpfrehanxi");
while (matcher.find()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        if (shortest == null || matcher.group(i).length() < shortest.length()) {
            shortest = matcher.group(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: explain your question little bit.

Comment: What do you find out in the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks with this code it works :

```
String shortest = null;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?=(d.*?o.*?a))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("ondjswxaeqobdnoajezbpfrehanxi");
while (matcher.find()) {
for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
    if (shortest == null || matcher.group(i).length() < shortest.length()) {
        shortest = matcher.group(i);
    }
}
```

Which is better ?

Answer (score 1):

```
djswxaeqobdnoa
d....*..o..*.a
```

That's one match of your regular expression consuming the full `String`.

Answer (score 0):

You are matching the whole `String`, hence the whole `String` is returned by your `group` invocation.

If you want specific matches of each segment of your `Pattern`, you only need to group those segments.

For instance:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(d.*?)(o.*?)a");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("djswxaeqobdnoa");
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
    // specific groups are 1-indexed
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

**Output**

```
djswxaeqobdnoa
djswxaeq
obdno
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is `d.*?o.*?a` and the string you want to compare is `djswxaeqobdnoa`.

starts with letter d and match the shortest possiblity in which the next character would be `o`. So it matches from `d` to first `o`.Because of nongreedyness `.*?` again it matches the shortest possiblity from `o` to the next shortest `a`. Thus it matches the whole string.